# Is it not possible to use $in inside of $or?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to filter my database with a list of keywords and the way I'm doing it right now is I'm using an $or across all my model fields and for each field using an $in to check across all the keyword regex's.

key_exps is an array of regexs. For my testing it is an array with just one element: /good/i.

```
//This is my code that I'm trying to fix:    
Ingredient.find({$or:[
    {name: {$in: key_exps}}, 
    {number: {$in: key_exps}},
    {vendor_info: {$in: key_exps}},
    {package_size: {$in: key_exps}},
    {cost: {$in: key_exps}},
    {comment: {$in: key_exps}}]
}, (err, ingredients) => {
    res.json({data: ingredients});
});

//This code works but doesn't allow me to search through multiple keywords:
Ingredient.find({$or:[
    {name: {$in: key_exps}}, 
    {number: {$in: key_exps}},
    {vendor_info: {$in: key_exps}},
    {package_size: {$in: key_exps}},
    {cost: {$in: key_exps}},
    {comment: key_exps.pop()}]
}, (err, ingredients) => {
    res.json({data: ingredients});
});

//This also works but doesn't allow me to search all fields:
Ingredient.find(
    {comment: {$in: key_exps}}, (err, ingredients) => {
    res.json({data: ingredients});
);
```

Comment: you might be interested in creating a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and using that instead